# How to Convert Datatables Value from Integer to String

Tags: javascript, datatables

I have a problem like my title. Here is the data I want to convert:

[image]

I want to convert `1` to `Active` and `0` to `Not Active`.

This is my datatables script:

```
$(function () {
            $('#userTable').DataTable({
                "paging": true,
                "lengthChange": true,
                "searching": true,
                "ordering": true,
                "info": true,
                "autoWidth": true,
                "scrollX": true,
                "ajax": {
                    "url" : "admin/auth/getUserData",
                    "dataSrc" : function(json) {
                        console.log(json);
                        return json.Users
                    }
                },
                "columns": [
                    { "data": "Username"},
                    { "data": "Email"},
                    { "data": "Fullname"},
                    { "data": "IdentityNumber"},
                    { "data": "InstitutionName"},
                    { "data": "UserStatus"},
});
        });
```

In our logic, it must be

```
if("data":"UserStatus" == 1)
    document.write("Active");
else
    document.write("Not active");
```

I've tried the code above but it failed to get the output I want. Can anybody help me fix this? Thanks

Comment: I believe you missed the "columns" part of it, so it doesn't know where to actually check and get the value 1
Could you show us the HTML that you're using for this section as well?

Comment: you have some syntax error in your code. [ is not closed.

Comment: The line `if("data":"UserStatus" == 1)` is not valid JavaScript.

Comment: try to get value by ID or class , then check inside if condition

Comment: to convert string to integer u can use parseInt.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use a [**`columns render`**](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render) function to do that :

```
"columns": [
   { "data": "Username"},
   { "data": "Email"},
   { "data": "Fullname"},
   { "data": "IdentityNumber"},
   { "data": "InstitutionName"},
   { "data": "UserStatus",
      render : function(data) {
         return data == '0' ? 'Not Active' : 'Active';
      }
   }
]
```